# Method called when layouting is done?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm looking for a method that I could override or some listener that is fired when a `JPanel` is being layouted. Checked the javadoc but couldn't find one. The situation is this:

- I have a component that takes care about **its contents** via a `Null-Layout`.
- The **component itself** is however layouted inside another `JPanel` (with a layout manager) and receives a certain size when layouting is done.
- Now I want to use this size to calculate widths and heights of the **contents** of that `Null-Layout JPanel.`

But of course I need to know when I have to recalculate sizes. Any ideas or a good alternative approach? The required calculating in the `Null-Layout` is actually very simple and using a layout manager would probably require more work than the current solution - I just need to find that method or listener.

Comment: "Don't use setSize, setLocation or setBounds on components. You should rely on an appropriate layout manager. Modern UIs are expected to run on different platforms with different screen resolutions, dpi, font metrics and rendering pipelines all of which effects the size of text on the screen..." - MadProgrammer

Comment: @Solace: After thinking about it, I agree. While my method might work most of the time, my overall goal is to improve my coding skills at all times, so I think I will have to use Layout Managers. It will be more work, but it's definitely cleaner.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: For the sake of the question I would still be interested in an answer. What method can I use to detect if a relayouting is needed?

Comment: `invalidate` and `doLayout` are called during the layout process.  You'd have to do some digging, but I believe once `invalidate` is called, there is an expectation that the container might be called upon to provide sizing hints...why not just write your own layout manager instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself so this can be closed.

`doLayout` will be called when layouting is needed, so that's the method one can override when doing layouts without a layout manager.